# What is wrong with this Python code? Refuses input

Tags: python

Every time I enter 4, 6 or 12 it doesn't accept it. Why? The code looks fine to me. Please tell me how to correct or what to change.

```
import random
def roll_the_dice():

    print("Roll The Dice")
    print()
    repeat = True

    while repeat:
        number_of_sides = input("Please select a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides: ")
        if (number_of_sides in [4,6,12] and len(number_of_sides) == 0 and 
            number_of_sides == int):
            user_score = random.randint(1,number_of_sides)
            print("{0} sided dice thrown, score {1}".format(
                                     number_of_sides,user_score))
            roll_again = input("Do you want to roll the dice again? ")
            roll_again.lower()
            if roll_again == "no":
                print("Have a nice day")
                repeat = False
            elif len(roll_again) == 0:
                print("Error please type 'yes' or 'no'")
                roll_again = input("Do you want to roll the dice again? ")
        else:
            print("You have entered an incorrect value, please try again")
            number_of_sides = input("Please select a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides: ")
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it accepts any value. `number_of_sides` cannot simultaneously be one of 4, 6, or 12 *and* be a string of length 0. In no case can you enter a string that is equal to the type `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haidro gave you the reason, but here is a different way to approach your problem:

```
def get_dice_size():
    dice_size = input('Enter the number of sides on the dice: ')
    while dice_size not in ['4','6','12']:
       print 'Sorry, please enter one of 4, 6 or 12:'
       dice_size = input('Enter the number of sides on the dice: ')
    return int(dice_size)

def main():
   dice_size = get_dice_size()
   repeat = True

   while repeat:
       print('Rolling the dice...')
       user_score = random.randint(1,dice_size)
       print("{0} sided dice thrown, score {1}".format(dice_size,user_score))
       roll_again = input("Do you want to roll the dice again? ")
       if roll_again.lower() == 'yes':
           dice_size = get_dice_size()
       else:
           repeat = False

   print('Thank you for playing!')
```

Comment: OP is using python 3, I'm presuming by the syntax. So `print()` and not `print` :)

Comment: Well, strictly speaking `print()` will work in Python 2.7 as well, but you are probably right.

Comment: Also, this looks really clean. I'm upvoting this.

Answer (score 7):

In Python 3, when using `input()`, it returns a *string*. Thus, you would have something like `"4"`. And `"4" is not 4`.

So in your script, specifically at the `if number_of_sides in [4,6,12]`, it will always be `False`, because you are really saying `if "4" in [4,6,12]` (I'm just doing 4 as an example).

Convert the string to an integer:

```
>>> int("4")
4
```

---

It also looks like you are trying to determine if an input was given. `len(...) == 0` is not needed. You can just say `if number_of_sides`. Because an empty string is `False`, and if one was entered, then the if-statement will not execute.

---

Also, `number_of_sides == int` is not the way to check if an object is an integer. Use `isinstance()`:

```
>>> isinstance("4", int)
False
>>> isinstance(4, int)
True
```

---

Some other tiny things:

- `.lower()` does not sort the string in place, as strings are immutable in python. You might just want to attach `.lower()` onto the end of the `input()`.
- You might also want to use a `while` loop for your second input. Observe:

  ```
  roll_again = ''
  while True:
      roll_again = input('Do you want to roll the dice again? ')
      if roll_again in ('yes', 'no'):
          break
      print("You have entered an incorrect value, please try again")

  if roll_again == "no":
      print("Have a nice day")
      repeat = False
  else:
      print("Let's go again!")
  ```

Comment: Even if it was an integer, calling len() on it doesn't work. Maybe it should be `n in ['4', '6', '12']` instead?

Comment: `number_of_sides == int` would also always return `False`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Or just `if int(number_of_sides) in [4, 6, 12]`, but you are absolutely correct yes.

Comment: There is too much wrong that doesn't work. The OP should have made smaller steps and/or reduced the code to the smallest possible piece that doesn't behave as expected. Oh, and saying the exact error and expectations help, too.

Comment: how about if i do `int(input("Please select a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides: "))`

Comment: @AhmedAbukar Yes, that will convert a string to an integer, which will fix some of your problems :)

Comment: @Haidro Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "H:\Controlled Assessment\Task 1 - Simulating a dice\ControlledAssessment.py", line 14, in roll_the_dice
    if number_of_sides in [4,6,12] and len(number_of_sides) == 0 and number_of_sides == int:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: @AhmedAbukar I've put that in my answer. Simply, there is no need for the `len()`.

Comment: the problem is the `len(number_of_sides)` part it doesnt work with int

Comment: @AhmedAbukar You are correct. You can use `str()`, which converts a type into a string. So `len(str(number_of_sides))` should work

Comment: @Haidro But if `number_of_sides` is an `int`, `len(str(number_of_sides))` will never be `0`. Better remove it entirely.

Comment: @tobias_k It really depends on what the OP is aiming for. I think OP is trying to detect whether any input was given, and in my answer I've talked about this

Answer (score 0):

You should change your script like shown below.

This is the important part:

```
    try:
        number_of_sides = int(input("Please select a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides: "))
    except ValueError:
        wrong = True
```

Convert to `int` right at input time with `int(input("…`. If the user enters anything that cannot be converted into an integer Python will raise a `ValueError`. You can catch this, show a message and go to the start of the loop with `continue`.

```
import random


def roll_the_dice():

    print("Roll The Dice")
    print()
    repeat = True

    while repeat:
        wrong = False
        try:
            number_of_sides = int(input("Please select a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides: "))
        except ValueError:
            wrong = True
        if wrong or number_of_sides not in [4,6,12]:
            print("You have entered an incorrect value, please try again")
            continue
        else:
            user_score = random.randint(1,number_of_sides)
            print("{0} sided dice thrown, score {1}".format(
                                     number_of_sides,user_score))
            roll_again = input("Do you want to roll the dice again? ")
            if roll_again in ('y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes'):
                continue
            else:
                print("Have a nice day")
                repeat = False

roll_the_dice()
```

Comment: Logic here needs some work. Conder at the first while loop, someone enters "1356"; what will happen?

Comment: 1356 is not in `[2, 4, 6]` so `else` gets these. Screen output:

$ `Please select a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides: 1356` 

$ `You have entered an incorrect value, please try again`

$ `Please select a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides: `

Comment: And then after that? It will ask again `"Please select a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides:"`, even if I enter `4` at the second prompt :)

Comment: @MikeMüller is there anyway of doing with the `try:` method